# Understanding $this->getIncludes()

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, phtml, head

I am using Magento 1.7. In `head.phtml`, the last line calls getIncludes(), like this

`<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>`

What exactly is this function including in the page head? I am not able to distinguish which scripts (or other lines) come from `getIncludes()` and which not.

Is it harmful to remove this line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check in block file `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`

you can see `function getIncludes()`

```
 /**
     * Get miscellanious scripts/styles to be included in head before head closing tag
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIncludes()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
            $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
        }
        return $this->_data['includes'];
    }
```

Its take script and css from  Miscellaneous Scripts field from `system->configuration->General->Design->Html Head`

see below screenshot
[image]

Is it harmful to remove this line of code?

Its dpend on you if you have any js or css there or if you planning to add it in future.

Comment: Thank you. I see a strange behavior. I have a chat, from Zopim, which is defined as a script in the head. When I remove getIncludes it disappears, but when I look into miscellaneous Scripts I can't find it there. Any ideas on where could it be defined? That has been included long time ago in the website and I don't have information on how it was done.

Comment: if you have databse access just serach `design/head/includes` in `core_config_data` table in path coloumn and see value